# Substitute command into remote sed command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, command-substitution

I want to write a Unix command which select a random user from /etc/passwd and check a remote host using SHH to determine if a user with the same UID exists, print out the full line from passwd if the user exists.

Here is the command I wrote so far:

```
echo `shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 3' | ssh 100.64.0.2  sed -n -e '/**xargs**/p' /etc/passwd
```

Seems like the sed command doesn't take xargs as a argument from local machine, but a text

Any idea would be very appreciated!

Comment: `xargs` is a command not a magic string that means "value from input".

Comment: why don't you take the whole etc/passwd and compare it to local one ? it's not really slower and lot more secure

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you were trying to write something like this

```
user=$(shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 3)
ssh 100.64.0.2  sed -n -e "/$user/p" /etc/passwd
```

But you might also want to look into using `getent` instead.

```
user=$(shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 3)
ssh 100.64.0.2  getent passwd "$user"
```

As I said in my comment on the OP `xargs` is a command. It isn't magic that will read a value from standard input and stick it on the command line. (Note that there's an ordering problem with that even as a concept since the command line, by definition, is constructed before any standard input can possibly exist.)

Comment: ssh 100.64.0.2  $(shuf -n 1 <(getent passwd) | cut -d ":" -f 3)

Comment: What you wrote is superfluous for one and furthermore undoes itself. Check your logic, I fixed it for you. =)

Comment: @A.Danischewski You are passing the UID of a random system user as the command to the remote system. How is that *at all* relevant to the question the user asked or even a valid thing to do? What about my examples "undoes itself"? And yes, you could certainly avoid the `$user` variable but there is little reason to do so in this case and using the varialbe makes the distinction between local command and remote command much more clear.

Comment: When you do shuf -n 1 /etc/passwd you get a line from passwd like mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh after you get the third field the UID in this case 8 - after you do an ssh and pass getent passwd "$user" - first of all you need to write it like ssh 100.64.0.2 $(getent passwd "$user") and second of all if you did that getent passwd "$user" with 8 returns you back the full string from the passwd file that you started with mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh

Comment: @A.Danischewski We are trying to run the `getent` and `sed` commands **on the remote host** not locally. We are trying to get the output **from the remote host** for the UID fetched from the local system. And yes, we are trying to get back the `passwd` file entry for that UID **from the remote host**.

Comment: That makes more sense, but in the first ssh the sed will return a match anywhere so you probably want to relegate it to only the 3rd field: eg. ssh 100.64.0.2 sed -e -n "/^[^ ]*:[^ ]*:$user:/p" /etc/passwd

Comment: @A.Danischewski Fair point. I just copied the OP's script. Using `sed` for this is wrong in the first place so I'm not particularly inclined to bother fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in `cat hostlist.txt`; do echo "### $f ###";  ssh $f find / -name "tmp" | sed "s/^/'$f  | '/" ;  done 2>/dev/null
```

i had difficult time to print hostname for each line of a find command, this helps to solve.